# graphics grid legend

Tags: graphics, legending

I'm working with mathematica 9.0 and I want to make a graphic grid containing 3 different plots. My problem is that when I use plotlegend to label the plots the legend does not show up or the left axis of the first plot it's out of the graphic. Does anybody know how can I label the three different plots without these issues?.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Grid instead of GraphicsGrid. See the difference:

```
p = {Framed@Plot[#@x, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"] & /@ {Sin, Cos, Tan}};
Framed@Grid@p
Framed@GraphicsGrid@p
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I've solved my problem. I have three graphics: two in a row and another below. I would know if can I center the graph below or make it larger. My code is like GraphicsGrid[{{ListLinePlot[{cont1, cont2}, 
    PlotRange -> {{0, 2}, {0, 500}}, Frame -> True, 
    FrameLabel -> {r, V[r]\[CenterDot]r^(2 + L' + L)}, 
    ImageSize -> 500, 
    PlotLegends -> Placed[{"cont1", "cont2"}, {0.9, 0.8}], 
    PlotStyle -> {Blue, Orange}]@